# How do I fix these eyes for a 3d print mold?

Tags: sculpting, 3d-printing

I'm trying to create a 3d-printed mold to cast a concrete bust. So, my understanding is to create a mold I'm not actually creating a 3d model of a head, but a 3d model of its **negative**.

That's where I ran into trouble. I used the software Character Creator 4 to craft the head since I find their sliders helpful to finesse fine details and make the character I envision in my head. But that gave me the head and eyes as separate objects since these characters come fully rigged.

[image]

As you can see, these eyes are full spheres. If I print a negative, that will be a huge problem, lol. I only want the part of the eyes that *isn't* inside the head/covered by the eyelids on my model.

I don't want to start over and sculpt this character from scratch because I'm not the best sculptor and I'm very happy with what I've got. So what am I to do? I tried cutting away most of the eye that was inside the head, then snapping the eye vertices onto the eyelid vertices to match, but it ended up deforming the eye shape and giving it a slightly tinfoil-y, angular look.

I can't just have empty eye sockets, lol.

On another related note, my plan so far was to take the final sculpture and use the solidify modifier to extrude it out in order to make my negative mold. But if anyone has a better idea, I'm all ears.

[image][image]

Comment: I think this is a bit too broad for BSE. I mean what you need is to model it correctly using modelling tools, but how is anyone going to teach you modelling in a single answer?.. Maybe tell us what you have tried and what you are struggling with to narrow this down a bit.

Comment: Also it would help if you show us the model. It's impossible to understand what that is from the screenshot. Some 3d printing slicers have "mold" mode for this, so it makes sense to first work on the model as it is.

Comment: Have you tried a Boolean operation/modifier (Union option) to merge the eyes with the body?

Comment: You would just need to sill the space left between the eyelids with a segment of a sphere, appropriately detailed. Please share a representative file on https://blend-exchange.com/, so someone can demonstrate how to do it in your case.

Comment: Okay, I edited the post to show more pictures. First is where I removed the eyes. Second is a copy with the eyes still intact.

Comment: At the moment, I'm actually considering printing the eyes and head separately and then sanding them and attaching them together afterward. 

But I'm not ready to make that decision yet. I could model the eyes. I'm actually an okay modeler and I'm planning to model the hair. I guess my concern was that it would be hard to round out the eyes without also stretching out the eyelids, but perhaps if I zoomed in enough and used enough detail that wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Robin, I'm not entirely sure I understand your suggestion, probably because I'm a newb. Hopefully the images help.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=MP6MxjYG" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/MP6MxjYG/)